# What's is th best way to manage pictures WP 8.1

Tags: c#, image, base64, windows-phone-8.1

Actually I'm developing an "social" app for my office and I'm wondering what's the best way to load or manage pictures. Each user has a profil picture and I would like to display it wherever I want, on the profil view, in the contacts list (little smaller) for example. When the user creates its profil, he picks up a picture from the picture library on his phone and it's send to server as base64 encoded string. The code that I've used to save the picked picture on the server (SQL Server 2012 database):

```
var reader = new DataReader(pictureStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
byte[] bytes = new byte[pictureStream.Size];
await reader.LoadAsync((uint)pictureStream.Size);
reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
string bytesString = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

So here **bytesString** contains the base64 encoded picture to send on the server. Atually, I'm facing two problems.

**First problem**:

The base64 encoded string cannot be inserted to the database even if the column type is **varchar(max)**. The string is cut in the table.

**Second problem**:

If I want to build the picture from bytesString decoding the base64 string, it takes so much time that it's not possible to work like that.

So I'm wondering how applications such **Instagram** or other picture specialized application are managing pictures so well... Does anyone could give me some advises to manage pictures through an app ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Use BitmapImage to store the actual image

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to mind:

**1. Store the images in a binary-type column**

I haven't used SQL server very much, but I guess there is a binary column type in which you can just store the original bytes of the image.

**2. Store the images in files instead of the database.**

Another thing you can do is to simply store the images in files with names based on the users' IDs (i.e. *user_15.png*).

**Other considerations**

Is there any reason to encode/decode the bytes? Sending the original image seems like a better option to me.

How are you actually sending the encoded image bytes? From what I understand `varchar(max)` should be able to hold quite a lot of data. Are you sure the server receives the right data?

On the client (in the WP 8.1 app) you may want to cache the images, so that you wouldn't need to load them from the server every time.